# How can I explain the difference between 'suppose', 'assume', and 'presume'?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

My boss tends to overuse the word "suppose". He'll say stuff like

> I suppose you received my email?

Now, clearly there are more things wrong with that sentence than just using "suppose" in a context where "presume" or "assume" would be much more idiomatic: to start with, if he wanted to ask a question, he should have asked a question, instead of merely tacking on a question mark (or rather, the corresponding inflection, since this was spoken, not written) to the end of a statement. But let's just stick to word choice for now.

The dictionary definitions of *presume*, *assume*, and *suppose* make them seem pretty much interchangeable.

> **[presume](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/presume)**: to take for granted, assume, or suppose
>   **[suppose](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suppose)**: to assume (something), as for the sake of argument or as part of a proposition or theory
>   **[assume](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/assume)**: to take for granted or without proof: *to assume that everyone wants peace*. Synonyms: suppose, presuppose; postulate, posit.

But to my ear, *suppose* is the wrong word to use in most situations.

> I suppose you are using Internet Explorer.

This is perfectly understandable — idiomatic, even, if delivered with the appropriate sneer — but to me, it means something quite different than

> I assume you are using Internet Explorer.

However, I have been utterly unable to articulate what the difference is, at least not in a manner that gets my point across to my boss.

Comment: I found a similar question on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396/assume-presume-suppose

Comment: By the way, phrasing a question as a statement and raising the end of the sentence is pretty common.

Answer (score 8):

To ***suppose*** that something is true means to think that it is true, but to freely acknowledge that it may just as well be false.  To ***assume*** that something is true means to act as if it were true, but with no implication that there is proof that it is.  To ***presume*** that something is true is to base an assumption of truth on some sort of probability or evidence.

So, *"I suppose you are using Internet Explorer"* is a slightly weaker assertion than *"I assume you are using Internet Explorer."*  For an example of presume: *"One may presume that he is using Internet Explorer, because he is using Windows and is a computer novice."*

These are not hard-and-fast rules; as you have seen the meanings overlap to some degree.  This is especially true of suppose and assume.